# Why do I need a Tab here?

Tags: python

Why does this code here only work when i put a tab bevore writing the print command?

I tried it without the tab an then i get the following error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 2
    print(fruit)

>>> fruit_inventory = {"apples": 5, "pears": 2, "oranges": 9}
>>> for fruit in fruit_inventory:
...     print(fruit)
...
oranges
apples
pears
```

i thought the command would work without the tab but this isnot the case.
Whats the reason for this?

Comment: Because indentations matter in Python

Comment: you should probably use 4 spaces instead of a tab

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html

Comment: In Python, scopes are defined by indentations. In Java, scopes are defined by curly brackets. So if you don't place a `tab` before your `print()` call, Python will complain that your syntax is wrong, since it expects an indented scope after a colon (after your for-loop).

Answer (score 0):

Loops, conditions all need 4 spaces (actually any amount is okay but 4 is most common, also you can't have mixed spaces) in the next line, to know when you need it, just check if you have a colon at the end of the line above (usually interpreters automatically indent by 4 spaces), see [the documentation of it](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html) (currently the best link I can find).

But if you do something like:

```
    print('Hello World') # notice the 4 spaces
```

It will break because you **can't** use indentation in the above example.